# Django-Rest Testing: 1) Cannot assign foreign key value while testing serializer (2) Interger field accepts float value

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, django-testing

Context: I am writing the test cases for testing the django model and serializer for a django-rest api.

Models.py looks like this:

```
from django.db import models
import uuid

class User(models.Model):
    user_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    second_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def getuuid(self):
        return str(self.user_id)

class Workout(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=False, blank=False, default=None, db_column='user_id')
    hours = models.FloatField()
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                check=models.Q(hours__gte=0),
                name="Hours should be positive"
            )
        ]

class Vacation(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=False, blank=False, default=None, db_column='user_id')
    times = models.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                check=models.Q(times__gte=1) & models.Q(times__lte=15),
                name="Valid range is 1 to 15 inclusive"
            )
        ]
```

Serializer.py looks like this:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import User, Workout, Vacation

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model= User
        fields= '__all__'

class WorkoutSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model= Workout
        fields= '__all__'

class VacationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model= Vacation
        fields= '__all__'
```

tests.py looks like this:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from .models import *
from .serializers import *

class UserTest(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        super(UserTest, cls).setUpTestData()
        cls.u1 = User.objects.create(
            first_name = "Jack",
            second_name = "Mueller",
            #hours = 3.5,
            #times = 3
        )

        cls.w1 = Workout.objects.create(
            hours = 2,
            user_id = cls.u1
        )

        cls.t1 = Vacation.objects.create(
            times = 2.5,
            user_id = cls.u1
        )

        cls.w2_val = {
            "hours":6,
            "user_id": cls.u1
        }
        cls.w2 = Workout.objects.create(**cls.w2_val)
        cls.w2_ser = WorkoutSerializer(cls.w2)
        cls.w2_deser = WorkoutSerializer(data=cls.w2_val)


    def test_user_model(self):
        self.assertEquals(len(User.objects.all()), 1)
    
    def test_serializer(self):
        print(self.w2_deser.is_valid()) # return False
        print(self.w2_deser.errors)    # {'user_id': [ErrorDetail(string='“User object (3a598312-5f3d-4adb-b4fc-c415fb024e8a)” is not a valid UUID.', code='invalid')]}
```

My Questions:

1. Why do I get False for **w2_deser.is_valid()** ?
2. How do I resolve the subsequent error (w2_deser.errors)? I tried setting user_id=cls.u1.user_id, this too did not address the issue.
3. Although the **times** field in the **Vacation** class is defined as an Integer, it accepts the floating point value. What is the reason behind this and how do I address it? (I tried defining custom validators but it did not work.)

I have done my fair bit of scavenging the internet for solution/information and also referred the official documentation. However, my questions remain unresolved. I am fairly new to Django and Rest. So any advice on the matter will be gladly welcomed. Thank you.

Comment: In `w2_val`, you need to use `"user_id": cls.u1.user_id`

Comment: I had tried that earlier like I mentioned in my second point. But it gives an error saying the field should have be an instance of User.

Comment: It's different. `w2_deser` is using `cls.w2_val` which is a dictionary. I was pointing out to change the dictionary key `user_id` of `cls.w2_val` to use `cls.u1.user_id` instead of `cls.u1`. Your second point seems to be about `cls.w1` and `cls.t1`.

Comment: I tried that and I get the following error: `ValueError: Cannot assign "UUID('......')": "Workout.user_id" must be a "User" instance`.